# Can't play video with Windows XP and IE8

Tags: video.js

I can't have the player working on IE8 with win xp (works well on IE8 with win 7)

I have two "source" tag with one ogv file and one mp4 file.

The player tags are added to the dom with ajax.
Then, the video-js player is loaded with `"_V_("videoID", ...`"
As said before, it works well with newer configurations, so the code is right.

If the player tags are not added to the dom with ajax, it works well. But in my case, I need to add them this way.

What I see when I load the page is that the player is there, the big play button is there. When I click play, I get the beginning of the video then it stops. Furthermore, the video is not in the good resolution, it's smaller and in the top left corner!

See picture (black is the player, and the white square is the badly shrinked video ): 
[image]

In addition to that, I have a javascript error on line 1191 :
(I tried to comment out the line just to see what happens but no change)

```
handle.el.style.left = _V_.round(adjustedProgress * 100, 2) + "%";
```

Using : Version 3.2.0

Thanks for any help

PS: sound can be heard but it's all jerky and CPU hits 100% when playing

Comment: video.js does not support <ie9, so you might have troubles.

Comment: i thought it would support it as a "flash browser" with mp4 :-/

Comment: @Michel, you’re right. The mention of IE9+ support on videojs.com refers to the browser having native HTML5 video support. Directly underneath that it's stated that it supports playback of MP4 on "all Flash browsers". Can you add some code or link?

Comment: here is a test link : http://www.chu.ulg.ac.be/jcms/c_1719129/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug!

I used the "seekIntro" function when the video is loaded.

When I remove the ".addEvent" line it works fine!

```
_V_("videoTag-<%=luo_Video.getId()%>").ready(function(){
    myPlayer = this;
    myPlayer.addEvent("loadeddata", seekIntro);     
});
function seekIntro(){
    myPlayer.currentTime(4);
}
```